# How to switch an active link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm using symfony2 (MVC framework) and Twitter Bootstrap v3.0.0. I'm trying to switch the `class"active"` everytime I click on a link. I tried many jquery solutions, the best one doesn't load the page. Here is my HTML code:

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top wet-asphalt" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_homepage') }}">Accueil</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_about') }}">A propos</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_projects') }}">Portfolio</a></li>                        
                <li><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_blog') }}">Blog</a></li>                        
                <li><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header><!--/header-->
```

Jquery code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('ul.nav > li').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
            });
        </script>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I don't see the jquery solutions that you tried? Please show them by editing your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to set active class to the opened link you can do something like this:

```
{% set page_route = app.request.attributes.get('_route') %}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li {% if page_route == 'portofolio_front_homepage' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_homepage') }}">Accueil</a></li>
    <li {% if page_route == 'portofolio_front_about' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_about') }}">A propos</a></li>
    <li {% if page_route == 'portofolio_front_projects' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_projects') }}">Portfolio</a></li>                        
    <li {% if page_route == 'portofolio_front_blog' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_blog') }}">Blog</a></li>                        
    <li {% if page_route == 'portofolio_front_contact' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ path('portofolio_front_contact')}}">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not easy to 'fix' your code, when you don't provide the JS.
Should be someng like this:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');
});
```

**Sample**
http://jsfiddle.net/a3yFh/

Comment: It doesn't work. When the page load, it returns to the first link.

Comment: @BaccouchTaieb That's because javascript doesn't keep on page loads. You have your html set to have the first link active when the page loads.

Comment: @sharf : how can I fix it?

Comment: @BaccouchTaieb You need some javascript that detects what page you are on, and run a modified version of Smamatti's script on page load to change the active link to the current page.